# Best way to tar and zip files meeting specific name criteria?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zip, tar

I'm writing a shell script on a Linux machine to be run via a crontab which is meant to move all files older than the current day to a new folder, and then tar and zip the entire folder. Seems like a simple task but for some reason, I'm running into all kinds of roadblocks. I'm new to this and self-taught so any help or redirection would be greatly appreciated.

## Specific criteria for which files to archive:

- All log files are in `/home/tech/logs/` and all pdfs are in `/home/tech/logs/pdf`
- All files are over a day old as indicated by the file name (file name does not include `$CURRENT_DATE`)
- All files must be `*.log` or `*.pdf` (i.e. don't archive files that don't include `$CURRENT_DATE` if it isn't a log or pdf file.

## Filename formatting specifics:

All the log file names are in `home/tech/logs` in the format `NAME 00_20180510.log`, and all the pdf files are in a "pdf" subdirectory (`home/tech/logs/pdf`) with the format `NAME 00_20180510_00000000.pdf` ("20180510" would be whenever the file was created and the 0's would be any number). I need to use the name rather than the file metadata for the creation date, and all files (pdf/log) whose name does not include the current date are "old". I also can't just move all files that don't contain `$CURRENT_DATE` in the name because it would take any non-`*.pdf` or `*.log` files with it.

Right now the script creates a new folder with a new pdf subdir for the old files (`mkdir -p /home/tech/logs/$ARCHIVE_NAME/pdf`). I then want to move the old logs into `$ARCHIVE_NAME`, and move all old pdfs from the original pdf subdirectory into `$ARCHIVE_NAME/pdf`.

## Current code:

```
find /home/tech/logs -maxdepth 1 -name ( "*[^$CURRENT_DATE].log" "*.log" ) -exec mv -t "$ARCHIVE_NAME" '{}' ';'

find /home/tech/logs/pdf -maxdepth 1 -name ( "*[^$CURRENT_DATE]*.pdf" "*.pdf" ) -exec mv -t "$ARCHIVE_NAME/pdf" '{}' ';'
```

This hasn't been working because it treats the numbers in `$CURRENT_DATE` as a list of numbers to exclude rather than a literal string.

I've considered just using tar's exclude options like this:

```
tar -cvzPf "$ARCHIVE_NAME.tgz" --directory /home/tech/logs --exclude="$CURRENT_DATE" --no-unquote --recursion --remove-files --files-from="/home/tech/logs/"
```

But a) it doesn't work, and b) it would theoretically include all files that weren't `*.pdf` or `*.log` files, which would be a problem.

Am I overcomplicating this? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I would go about this using bash's extended glob features, which allow you to negate a pattern:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

mv /home/tech/logs/*!("$CURRENT_DATE")*.log "$ARCHIVE_NAME"
mv /home/tech/logs/pdf/*!("$CURRENT_DATE")*.pdf "$ARCHIVE_NAME"/pdf
```

With `extglob` enabled, `!(pattern)` expands to everything that doesn't match the pattern (or list of pipe-separated patterns).

Using `find` it should also be possible:

```
find /home/tech/logs -name '*.log' -not -name "*$CURRENT_DATE*" -exec mv -t "$ARCHIVE_NAME" {} +
```

Answer (score -1):

Building on @tom-fenech answer, optimized to avoid many `mv` invocations:

```
find /home/tech/logs -maxdepth 1 -name '*.log' -not -name "*_${CURRENT_DATE?}.log" | \
  xargs mv -t "${ARCHIVE_NAME?}"
```

An interesting feature, from processing the file thru pipes, is the ability to filter them with extra tools (aka grep :), which can (arguably) become more readable i.e. ->

```
find /home/tech/logs -maxdepth 1 -name '*.log' | fgrep -v "_${CURRENT_DATE?}" | \
  xargs mv -t "${ARCHIVE_NAME?}"
```

Then similarly for the `pdf` ones, *BTW* you can *"dry-run"* above by just replacing `mv` by `echo mv`.

--jjo

Comment: `-exec {} +` invokes the command as few times as possible based on the length of the resulting command line, similar to `xargs`. The difference is that your commands break in the pathological case of filenames that contain newlines, whereas mine don't.